# How to resize a UITextView in a Cell when changing from Portrait to Landscape?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ios5

I have a TextView made by code.

```
CGRect textFrame = CGRectMake(5, 20, 300, 50);

UITextView *textView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:textFrame];
```

The problem is, i want to resize it when landscape mode is called.

Here are some examples:

https://docs.google.com/file/d/0BzsX_FHtJa9nSjRVamtFX1pjdlE/edit?usp=sharing

https://docs.google.com/file/d/0BzsX_FHtJa9nU0U5T3JvZkgzZWc/edit?usp=sharing

Thanks

PS: This is just for iPhone. No iPad implementation.

Edit:

TableView code:

```
tableProducts.dataSource = self;
tableProducts.delegate = self;
tableProducts.bounces = YES;
```

Cell code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableProducts dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if(cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    cell.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;        
}

/* ------ Product title in RED ------*/

CGRect titleFrame = CGRectMake(5, 5, 250, 15);
UILabel *productTitle = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:titleFrame];
productTitle.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:14];
productTitle.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
productTitle.text = [listProducts objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

[cell.contentView addSubview:productTitle];

/* ------ Product title in RED ------*/

/* ------ Product Text ------*/

CGRect textFrame = CGRectMake(5, 20, 300, 50);
UITextView *textView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:textFrame];
textView.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
textView.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:11.5];
textView.text = [listTexts objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
textView.scrollEnabled = NO;
textView.editable = NO;

[cell.contentView addSubview:textView];

/* ------ Product Text ------*/

return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

set your text's autoresizing mask

```
 textview.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
```

Comment: I did that, but when I return to Portrait or viceversa... It gets a white line and text is cut.

Answer (score 1):

Just change the frame whenever you switch orientations. Return yes for shouldAutoRotate and then in willAnimateRotation just do something like this:

```
-(void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
    if(UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(toInterfaceOrientation))
    {
       textView.frame = CGRectMake(x,y,width,height)//whatever values you want for landscape
    }
    else
    {
       textView.frame = CGRectMake(x,y,width,height)//whatever values you want for portrait
    }
}
```

Comment: I keep having mounted views... Can I reload the table or something?

Comment: What do you mean mounted views? And this a tableViewController or standard uiviewcontroller?

Comment: Soooo it is a tableView then? We need details on the setup if you want help

Comment: if a cell is getting stuff constantly pasted on top of it, rather than clearing it out when you scroll then you are not building your cells correctly, and every time a cell is re-used you are stacking objects(labels, textfields etc) on top of each other.  you need to make sure you only add those objects at cell creation, and you only update their values when the cell is re-rendered